# Is it possible using "su -c" with multiple commands but in one session?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh-keys, openssh, ssh-agent

I am trying run the following two command in one command.

```
eval "$(ssh-agent)"
ssh add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I tried with many possible solutions:

```
su username -c "{ eval $(ssh-agent -s) }; ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa"
su username -c "eval $(ssh-agent -s)" ; ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
su username -c "eval $(ssh-agent -s)" && ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
su username -c "eval $(ssh-agent -s)" && "ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

It seems like the first command run successfully but the second either response with Permission denied message (means it run with the current user) or cannot connect to the authentication agent (means it probably created a new session for the second command).

Error messages:

```
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

```
Error connecting to agent: Permission denied
```

If I run them separately in order, it works:///

The purpose is to create a bash script with these commands with variables, something like this:

```
folder=/home/q12
username=q12

su $username -c "{ eval $(ssh-agent -s) }; ssh-add $folder/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

Because of the variables I can not quote the whole command because it will be sensitive to ";" and "&&".

Can anyone help me with this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need single quotes. Otherwise the command substitution is evaluated in the current context.

```
su username -c 'eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"; ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa'
```

Edit:

To get conditional execution of `ssh-add`, you can do:

```
su username -c 'script=$(ssh-agent -s) || exit 1; eval "$script"; ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa'
# or
su username -c 'set -e; script=$(ssh-agent -s); eval "$script"; ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa'
```

The argument in `su -c STRING` is a command *string*, similar to `bash -c STRING`. We can also nest double quotes inside single quotes.

Comment: It works! Thank you! 
I tried it but with variable inside. Anyway, I can leave that variable...
Thank you so much again!

Answer (score 0):

The first of your tries is closest, but inside double-quotes things like `$(ssh-agent -s)` get evaluated by your shell *before* they're passed to `su` as part of an argument. Net result: the ssh agent is running under the current user, so the other user can't use it.

You need to delay evaluation until the other-user shell. Using single-quotes instead of double would do this, *but* in the actual command you have `$folder`, which you clearly want evaluated by *your* shell (it won't be defined in the other-user shell), so you *don't* want to delay evaluation of that. The simplest way to do this is to escape the `$` that you want to delay evaluation of (your shell will remove the escape, so the other-user shell will see & evaluate it):

```
su "$username" -c "eval \$(ssh-agent -s); ssh-add $folder/.ssh/id_rsa"
#                       ^ Note the escape
```

(BTW, I also added double-quotes around the username, as that's generally-good scripting hygiene. Quoting `$folder` is more complicated, and shouldn't be necessary as long as it doesn't contain any weird characters, so I skipped it. Also, the `{ }` weren't necessary, and if they were used there needed to be a `;` before the `}`... so I just removed them.)

Another option is to single-quote part of the command and double-quote another part (mixed quoting looks weird, but is perfectly legal in shell syntax):

```
    su "$username" -c 'eval $(ssh-agent -s);'" ssh-add $folder/.ssh/id_rsa"
#                     ^  single-quoted part ^^    double-quoted part      ^
```

The reason the rest of your attempts didn't work is that the delimiter between the commands (`;` or `&&`) wasn't in the quoted string, and hence was treated as a delimiter by *your* shell, so the second command was run under your user ID rather than as part of the `su` command.

Comment: For some reason I got the following error message with your methods:

sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "}")

Comment: @SnackK0515 D'oh, there was a semicolon missing before the `}`. Actually, the `{ }` weren't doing anything useful, so I just removed them. Try it now. Although that's not the error message I'd expect, so there might be something else going on as well. If removing `{ }` doesn't fix it, try replacing `su "$username" -c` with just `echo`, and see if the resulting command looks correct.